# getting started with mysqli and reading a fatal error

Tags: php, mysqli, mysql-error-1064

Here's the code

```
require_once 'functions.php';
require_once 'cfg.php';
$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}
$query='SELECT * FROM cobra';
$result=$mysqli->prepare($query);
$result->execute();
$result->close();
echo array_values($result);
```

I am getting error after error. Initially I had the query part contained in a function, but kept running into all sorts of issues with variable scope for $mysqli.

The most recent error is: **Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in ...cobra/lib/distro.php on line 11**

Line 11 is:

```
$result->execute();
```

I would like some background knowledge about the different ways to go about this. I am learning everything I can, but quickly approaching a deadline as well. Please help.

Comment: Is the result of `mysqli::prepare` false? If yes then see what [mysqli::error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) returns.

Comment: well that helped significantly. I'm trying methods on the wrong types of objects and variables! At least I know what to do now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check that `$result` is a valid `mysqli_stmt` object.

```
$query='SELECT * FROM cobra';
$result=$mysqli->prepare($query);
if ($result instanceof mysqli_stmt) {
    $result->execute();
} else {
    // determine what went wrong
    echo $mysqli->error;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The prepare is not returned a statement handle, but false, indicating that the prepare did not run as expected.

You could try this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
}
$query =' SELECT * FROM cobra';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
if (!$stmt)
  die($mysqli->error);

$stmt->execute();

echo array_values($stmt->fetch());

$stmt->close();
```

Comment: You use $result at the end, but it is not defined. Why is that?

Comment: Your $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query); is the same as my $result=$mysqli->prepare($query);

Comment: But I do some error checking after the prepare ..